# Ember - time function in controller not rendering in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

looking for suggestions on why this is not working.

here is products_controller

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  time: function() {
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    return time;
  }.property(),
  onSale: Ember.computed.alias('product.onsale');
});
```

the hbs template is as follows

```
<p>The time now is {{time}}</p>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can be more clear about what "not working" entails...

Comment: @BradWerth Sounds like you're just confused. If you read the title it might help you understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in an app using `ember-cli`, and it works fine (I get the time in seconds since the epoch).

Because of this, it seems like this could be a problem with the wiring up of the template & controller (such as the context for the template not being the controller or instance you think it is).

Another helpful tip for debugging this is to get the ember inspector:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

This can help show you what controller/route/model/view you are using for a given segment and you can validate it is correct.